# send file via bluetooth in c# application

Tags: c#, networking, bluetooth

i want to automatically detect all devices around my pc and send a file to them

i'm using brecham and inthehand dll's,

here is my codes :

```
        BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] info = null;
        info = bc.DiscoverDevices(999);
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in info)
        {
            lstDevices.Items.Add(device.DeviceName + device.DeviceAddress);
            device.Update();
            device.Refresh();
            device.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.ObexObjectPush, true);

            if (!device.Authenticated)
            {
                // Use pin "0000" for authentication
                if (!BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress, "0000")){
                    MessageBox.Show("Request failed");
                }

            }

            var file = @"C:\1.jpg";
            var uri = new Uri("obex://" + info[1].DeviceAddress + "/" + file);
            var request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
            request.ReadFile(file);
            var response = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            //check response.StatusCode
            response.Close();
        }
```

but i get the message "Request Failed!"
please can anyone correct me?

anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 4):

solved problem with a little change in the code's :

```
        if (!BluetoothRadio.IsSupported)
            MessageBox.Show("No Bluetooth device detected.");
        if (BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode == RadioMode.PowerOff)
            BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;
        MessageBox.Show(BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Name.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode.ToString());
        BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] info = null;
        info = bc.DiscoverDevices(999);
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in info)
        {
            lstDevices.Items.Add(device.DeviceName + " - " + device.DeviceAddress);
            device.Update();
            device.Refresh();
            device.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.ObexObjectPush, true);
            if (!device.Authenticated){
                // Use pin "0000" for authentication
                if (!BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress, "0000")){
                    MessageBox.Show("Request failed");
                }
            }
            var file = @"d:\1.jpg";
            var uri = new Uri("obex://" + device.DeviceAddress + "/" + file);
            var request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
            request.ReadFile(file);
            var response = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            // check response.StatusCode
            response.Close();
        }
```

hope it be usefull for you and everyone that need it :)

Comment: Thank you for such a good chunk of code! I just wand to add that you need to install 32feet.NET library from Nuget - it will add essential InTheHand.Net.Personal.dll to the project.